# Iterate through list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm trying to iterate through a list of Window object pointers with this code:

```
    auto windowPtr = reinterpret_cast<std::list<Window>*>(lParam);

    for (std::list<Window*>::const_iterator it = windowPtr.begin(); it != windowPtr.end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->handle == hwnd)
        {
            state = true;
        }
    }
```

But I get an error marking `windowPtr.begin()` and `windowPtr.end()` saying:

```
std::list<Window> *windowPtr   Error: expression must have class type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `windowPtr` is a pointer to a list, so you'd need to use `windowPtr->begin()`. However, that `reinterpret_cast` looks really suspicious. What is `lParam`?

Comment: you cast it to a `list<someType>*` (i.e. a pointer) but then you use `.` trying to access a method use `->` instead

Comment: your cast says `std::list<Window>*` and you iterator says `std::list<Window*>`: only 1 swap of characters makes 2 different types.  Which one is a mistake?

Comment: Or are they both wrong and you really mean `std::list<Window*>*`?

Comment: Could you provide some more context to your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::list<Window*>* windows = reinterpret_cast<std::list<Window*>>(lParam);
    bool state = false;
    for (std::list<Window*>::const_iterator it = windowPtr->begin(); it != windowPtr->end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->handle == hwnd)
        {
            state = true;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     std::list<Window*> windows;

     ...

     EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&windows);
}
```

or you could use some std function

```
state = std::find(windowPtr->begin(), windowPtr->end(), [=] (Window* w) {return w->handle == hwnd;}) != windowPtr->end();
```